# Doctrine OneToOne always loaded on querybuilder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

I have Partner entity with two relation:

```
/**
 * @var PartnerSettings
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="PartnerSettings", mappedBy="partner", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, fetch="LAZY")
 */
private $settings;

/**
 * @var PartnerRating
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="PartnerRating", mappedBy="partner", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, fetch="LAZY")
 */
private $rating;
```

...getRepository(Partner::class)->findAll() work correctly, one query was made,but when I create queryBuilder:

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

doctrine make 31 queries(i have 10 partners)... in debug toolbar i saw select queries to settings and rating for every partner. I don't want it in this case.
Additionally, in every querybuilder where I used join to partners, setting and rating are selected too.

> answer

> ```
> ->setHint(Query::HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD, true);
> ```

did the job

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is known as the [N + 1 selects problem](https://www.google.de/search?q=n%20%2B%201%20select). To reduce database queries, you might want to consider the following approach.

First, retrieve all partners:

```
$partners = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select("p")
    ->from("Parent", "p")
    ->where(/*...*/)
    ->setParameter(/*...*/)
    ->indexBy("p.id")
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Now load all children at once, in two queries:

```
$settings = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select("s")
    ->from("PartnerSetting", "s")
    ->where("IDENTITY(s.partner) IN (?1)")
    ->setParameter(1, array_keys($partners))
    ->getQuery()->getResult();

$ratings = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select("r")
    ->from("PartnerRating", "r")
    ->where("IDENTITY(r.partner) IN (?1)")
    ->setParameter(1, array_keys($partners))
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Doctrine will now have all of the retrieved entities are stored in memory. So when, for example, you do a `$parnter->getRatings()`, you don’t trigger a new DB query, instead the entity is filled from memory.

Answer (score 1):

just define the table AND the relation in the select

$qb->select('g', 'gi');

and now it works

Answer (score 0):

Just mapped relation: `@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="ENTITY", mappedBy="MAPPEDBY", fetch="EAGER")`

Comment: `eagerCursor` is for ODM, not ORM.

Comment: If you want to fix your answer, please edit it directly instead of commenting.